# MongoDB $lookup operation inside collection.aggregate not matching ObjectIDs that are equal to each other

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have, in the same database, the following two collections: `users` and `posts`.

Whenever a document inside `posts` is created server-side, an `ObjectID` field named `author` is added to the document that matches the author's `_id`.

For example:

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, the `ObjectID` properties are the same.

However, when I call the following `aggregate` method on the `posts` collection, the `$lookup` operation apparently fails, not adding an object.

[image]

Where `id` is an argument passed down to the function that contains the `string` for the `post` document, and `postsCollection` is `require('../db.js').db().collection('posts');`

---

**What I expected**

`posts` is an `array` containing just one `object`, that in turn contains the data for the `post` document with the `_id` property matching the incoming `id` argument.

This `object` should have all the properties from the document *and* one additional property named `'authorDocument'` that contains all the data from the `user` document.

---

**What happens**

`posts` is an `array` containing just one `object` with all the data from the relevant document. **However**, the `authorDocument` property is not added.

This is what I get by calling `console.log(posts[0])`:

[image]

---

**What I have tried**

I've created another post and also relogged (to create another session). Same problem.

I've also tried finding the document with another method: `collection.findOne` and it worked with the `author` property from `posts[0]` object.

[image]

gets me

[image]

I have also tried comparing the `author` field with the `_id` field from the user, by doing this:

[image]

It returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a very simple typo. I figured it while reading the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#aggregate).

There it says:
[image]

I hadn't listed the operations inside an `array` of operations, and that's why the second operation (`$lookup`) was not being recognized.

By adding the following brackets, the code now runs perfectly:

[image]